# Facebook batch operations custom object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to make some batch operations for custom objects that I have created oat Open graph API. I have seen tons of examples for feeds or images, but I still do not know if Facebook supports batch operations for custom objects. For example, I'd like to know if a batch operation for the following objects would work:

```
batch=[
{:method=>"post", :relative_url=>"/me/tfgtopquiz:win", "profile"=>"users/1/victories"} 
{:method=>"post", :relative_url=>"/me/tfgtopquiz:guessed", "triviaquestion"=>"questions/1"} ]
```

Notice that I have custom types (triviaquestion). It seems that if I pass it as a parameter facebook ignores it, and I would need this information. After the request, I get this error message:

> "The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: triviaquestion."

I really tried to define the type "triviaquestion", but it looks like Facebook ignored it iside batch JSON.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you encoding the parameters correctly? it doesn't look like you are from what i can see - check the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/  and compare to the first example under 'Batch requests containing multiple methods'

Comment: Hi! Yes, I am encoding the parameters; I am using Faraday gem to do this work. Thanks for the try anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I realized that I should send the JSON in other format:

```
{:access_token=>"MY_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
:requests=>
[{:action=>"guessed", :object_type=>"triviaquestion", :object_url=>"URL"},
{:action=>"guessed", :object_type=>"triviaquestion", :object_url=>"URL"},
{:action=>"guessed", :object_type=>"triviaquestion", :object_url=>"URL"},
{:action=>"play", :object_type=>"correct_answer", :object_url=>"URL"}]}
```

Thanks!